# How can I get effect of HTML into email's subject line?

Tags: email, html-email

I am using Apache Commons Email API  for sending email from my application. I am not able to get proper subject line of sent email. For example, problematic subject line: "`This is my email Subject line companyName<sup>®</sup>`". I expected subject line to be "`I want something likewise - companyName®`" but the superscript effect was not being displayed.

Comment: Most clients do not support rendering HTML in the subject line.

Comment: @Thilo, means possible or not?

Comment: Means if you send an email like that, almost everyone will see the raw HTML tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rendering of the subject line is performed by the email client; i.e. the tool that the recipient of the email uses to read his / her mail.  These tools implement a standard called RFC 822 which specifies how email represented; e.g. what the email headers are, and what them mean, and how the body (content) of the email is represented.

Here's the problem.  RFC 822 was specified in 1982.  That was many years before Unicode.  RFC 822 has been updated a couple of times, and the latest version is [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322).  However, RFC 5322 still retains the constraint that email header fields (such as the "Subject:" field) must be consist of ASCII characters.  (In other words, using UTF-8 directly in a subject would be a spec violation.)

Fortunately there is a workaround.  The [RFC 1342](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1342) standard provides a syntax for passing text that is encoded in another character encoding (such as UTF-8) via ASCII.  The MIME specifications have made it clear that
you can RFC 1342 encoding in email headers.

The general form of RFC 1342 encoding is:

```
    =?charset?encoding?encoded-text?=
```

where `charset` is a standard charset name, `encoding` is either `Q` or `B` (quoted string or base64), and `encoded-text` is the text represented in the nominated charset, and encoded using the nominated encoding.  For example:

```
    =?utf-8?Q?hello?=
```

Please refer to the RFC for more detail.

Note that if you use the `javax.mail` APIs to construct emails, the correct way to set a UTF-8 encoded email subject is like this:

```
    message.setSubject("We love Java® !!", "UTF-8");
```

or using Java's `\uxxxx` Unicode escapes.

Unfortunately, the Apache Commons Email API doesn't allow you to do that.  However (if I have read the code correctly), it will attempt to encode header fields containing non-ASCII characters using the email's character set (see `setCharset()`) or the default character set.

So, if a plain "`®`" was not passed correcly when using the Apache Commons Email API, the solution would be to use `setCharset("UTF-8")` to set the email's character set.  (In fact, the evidence is that the character is already being correctly handled, so this could be redundant.)

---

That addresses the issue of Unicode characters.  You also were trying to include HTML markup in the "Subject:".  HTML markup in mail headers is not supported by any email specifications, as far as I am aware.  Indeed, it would arguably be a spec violation if an emailer *did* attempt to render HTML markup in a Subject: header.

There is an alternative though, since Unicode allows you to modify a character to make it a subscript or superscript; see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) for details.  If you try this approach, you will be at the mercy of the recipient's email client's Unicode rendering.

Answer (score 0):

@stephen-c answer is correct, just to complement, I will share part of my code.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
....
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
String subject;
...
byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(subject.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
message.setSubject("=?UTF-8?B?" + new String(bytesEncoded) + "?=");
```